# How to autofill the other form field as per the value user entered in another field of the same form in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I am implementing application similar like bookers. There is one form that allows to book an appointment. If we enters an email address, the other information like Name, Phone Number and address should be automatically filled up from the database  from the previous appointments, as soon as I write email address. Following are the code blocks from my files:

**book.php**

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Customer Email*</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" name="email" required/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Booking Time*</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" name="name" required/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Service Name*</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" name="phone" required/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <? $cust = array($model->booking_history->cust_first_name, $model->booking_history->cust_last_name, $model->booking_history->cust_address,                $model->booking_history->cust_country, $model->booking_history->ship_city, $model->booking_history->cust_state, $model->booking_history->cust_zip);

   <div class="form-group">
       <label>First Name</label>
       <?php echo $model->form->textBoxFor('cust_first_name',['required'=>'required']); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Last Name</label>
       <?php echo $model->form->textBoxFor('cust_last_name',['required'=>'required']); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Address</label>
       <?php echo $model->form->textBoxFor('cust_address',['required'=>'required']); ?>
   </div>
```

I have Model **Book.php** with the similar fields as above. Also have **bookController.php** . Can anyone show me how can I implement this functionality, either by using Controller or by jQuery or AJAX if possible.

**EDIT:**
I have write the below code in my jQuery part:

```
$("input[name=email]" ).on( "focusout", function(){

 var emailValue = $(this).val();
 console.log(emailValue);
 $.post( "/abc/getBookingDetails", { email: email}, function( data ) {
    $("input[cust_first_name]").val( data['cust_first_name'] );

 } );
} );`
```

and in controller file:

```
 public function getBookingDetails(){
 $email = $_POST['email'];

 $res = [];
 $bookingDetails = \Model\Book::getList(['where'=>"email = '{$email}'"]);

 if($bookingDetails){
    $res = ['first_name' => $bookingDetails->first_name, 'last_name' => $bookingDetails->last_name];
 } else {

 }
}
```

But I am getting first name and last name as null. Where I am wrong? I am not using JSON to store and parse.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to edit my answer, so here is a working example. I have two files. One I named index.php and the other api.php. Both files in a directory named test.

FIRST FILE CONTAINS THE FORM AND JQUERY CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Customer Email*</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" name="email" required/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Booking Time*</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" name="name" required/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Service Name*</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" name="service_name" required/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Phone</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" name="phone" required/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>First Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="fname" required/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Last Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="lname" required/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="address" required/>
   </div>
    <script>
    $("input[name=email]" ).on( "focusout", function(){
     var emailValue = $(this).val();

     // This is the sample request
     $.get( "/test/api.php", { email: emailValue }, function( data ) {
        $("input[name=phone]").val( data.phone );
        $("input[name=fname]").val( data.fname );
        $("input[name=lname]").val( data.lname );
        $("input[name=address]").val( data.address );
     } );
    } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

SECOND FILE NAMED api.php THAT RECEIVE THE AJAX REQUEST

```
<?php

// Just a sample array. You will want to query for the data you need.
$resp = [
    'phone' => '###-###-####',
    'fname' => 'First Name',
    'lname' => 'Last Name',
    'address' => 'Address Street',
    'email_value' => $_GET['email']
];
// Set the json response header.
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// json encode the data
print json_encode($resp);
```

Comment: Edited the question. Implemented as you said but in different way without JSOn. Can you tell me why I am getting a null value even though I am getting all the details in '$bookingDetails' but a null in res ? I think my code syntax are wrong. If so, what's the correct way ?

Comment: I was asked to edit my answer vs sending a new one. My changes reflect a working set of code. Hope this helps, and if so, give an up vote if you would be so kind. Let me know if you have more questions?

Comment: By the way my revised answer is above ^^^